# sum up graphs from different streams but slightly different timestamps

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

Right now I try to solve a problem which seems for my understanding somehow related to [Finding gaps in huge event streams?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30610669/finding-gaps-in-huge-event-streams)

I have several streams of data in my table. I want to sum them up by time, but they have not always the same timestamp. The table looks like this:

Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ("id" int, "stream_id" int, "timestamp" timestamp, "value" real)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    ("id", "stream_id", "timestamp", "value")
VALUES
    (1, 7, '2015-06-01 15:20:30', 0.1),
    (2, 7, '2015-06-01 15:20:31', 0.2),
    (3, 7, '2015-06-01 15:20:32', 0.3),
    (4, 7, '2015-06-01 15:25:30', 0.5),
    (5, 7, '2015-06-01 15:25:31', 1.0),

    (6, 6, '2015-06-01 15:20:31', 1.1),
    (7, 6, '2015-06-01 15:20:32', 1.2),
    (8, 6, '2015-06-01 15:20:33', 1.3),
    (9, 6, '2015-06-01 15:25:31', 1.5),
    (10, 6, '2015-06-01 15:25:32', 2.0)    
;
```

My attempt to solve it:

```
with ts as (select "timestamp"       
           from Table1
           order by "timestamp"
          ),
data as (select "timestamp","value"
         from Table1
         order by "timestamp"
         ),
streams as (select "stream_id"        
           from Table1
           group by "stream_id"
           order by "stream_id"
          )          
select * .... (question)
```

I wish to get a graph line for all summed up data. When at a time, there is no data in the other streams, the sum should take the line, which `timestamp < current_timestamp` but nearest at the current time_stamp. If there is no value, assume 0.

I thought about recursive queries, but I somehow don't see the solution...

EDIT: Here I tried to explain it graphically:

[image: graphical description of my problem]

EDIT 2:

I think about something like this, but I don't get the last "thingy" to finish it.

```
with RECURSIVE data as (
    select * from rawdata 
    where date(date_time)='2014-05-01'
),
streams as (
    select stream_id from data 
    group by stream_id
),
t(n) AS (
    VALUES (1)
  UNION ALL
    SELECT n+1 FROM t WHERE n < (select count(*) from streams)
)
SELECT n FROM t;
```

Comment: I am a little confused on what you are asking. Do you just need the sum for each stream or the sum for each stream bucketed by time. If you need it bucketed, what is the resolution of your time buckets? I.E. do you want the sum of values for a stream by minute?, 5 minutes? etc...

Comment: I updated my question to explain it better. I dont want to sum them up by bucket or timeslice. I dont know how to explain it in english, so i tried to explain it by graphics.

Comment: How many numbers do you want to sum ? 3 or more ? The graph suggests that each sum consists of exactly 3 terms. Does it mean that you want to sum last 3 numbers, and each one must come from different stream ?

Comment: I have n streams and each sum is made of n summands. In the example: n = 3. Each element of the sum is from an other stream, or 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I apologize, there was an error in the previous query 
Here is a new, corrected query:

```
WITH times AS(
  SELECT DISTINCT "timestamp" As tm
  FROM table1
)
SELECT tm, SUM( val ) as s_u_m
FROM (
    SELECT tm, "stream_id",
           (  SELECT "value" FROM Table1 t2
              WHERE t2."timestamp" = max( t1."timestamp" )
                AND t2."stream_id" = t1."stream_id"
              ORDER BY "id" DESC LIMIT 1
            ) As val
    FROM times t
    JOIN table1 t1
    ON t.tm >= t1."timestamp"
    GROUP BY tm, "stream_id"
    order by tm
  ) you_must_have_an_alias_here_in_order_to_avoid_the_syntax_error
GROUP BY tm
ORDER BY tm;
;
```

and a demo with 3 streams in the source data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/30eb8/5

---

This is a source table with a layout that mimics the layout of your graph:

```
|  x | id |              timestamp | stream6 | stream7 | stream8 |
|----|----|------------------------|---------|---------|---------|
|  1 |  1 | June, 01 2015 15:20:30 |  (null) |     0.1 |  (null) |
|  2 |  2 | June, 01 2015 15:20:31 |  (null) |     0.2 |  (null) |
|  3 |  3 | June, 01 2015 15:20:31 |     1.1 |  (null) |  (null) |
|  4 |  4 | June, 01 2015 15:20:32 |  (null) |     0.3 |  (null) |
|  5 |  5 | June, 01 2015 15:20:32 |     1.2 |  (null) |  (null) |
|  6 | 11 | June, 01 2015 15:20:32 |  (null) |  (null) |     2.3 |
|  7 | 12 | June, 01 2015 15:20:32 |  (null) |  (null) |     1.1 |
|  8 | 10 | June, 01 2015 15:20:33 |     1.3 |  (null) |  (null) |
|  9 | 13 | June, 01 2015 15:20:33 |  (null) |  (null) |     1.7 |
| 10 |  6 | June, 01 2015 15:25:30 |  (null) |     0.5 |  (null) |
| 11 |  7 | June, 01 2015 15:25:31 |     1.5 |  (null) |  (null) |
| 12 |  8 | June, 01 2015 15:25:31 |  (null) |       1 |  (null) |
| 13 |  9 | June, 01 2015 15:25:32 |       2 |  (null) |  (null) |
```

---

**And the result is:** ( v(3) means: value from a record with x=3)

```
|                     tm |     s_u_m |
|------------------------|-----------|
| June, 01 2015 15:20:30 |       0.1 |  0    + v(1) + 0
| June, 01 2015 15:20:31 | 1.3000001 |  v(3) + v(2)  + 0
| June, 01 2015 15:20:32 |       2.6 |  v(5) + v(4) + v(7) => see note below !!!
| June, 01 2015 15:20:33 |       3.3 |  v(8) + v(4) + v(9)
| June, 01 2015 15:25:30 |       3.5 |  v(8) + v(10)+ v(9)
| June, 01 2015 15:25:31 |       4.2 |  v(11)+ v(12)+ v(9)
| June, 01 2015 15:25:32 |       4.7 |  v(13)+ v(12)+ v(9)
```

---

**Note for a record** `| June, 01 2015 15:20:32 |       2.6 |`

The source table in the demo contains two records with the same date and the same source_id:

```
|  6 | 11 | June, 01 2015 15:20:32 |  (null) |  (null) |     2.3 |
|  7 | 12 | June, 01 2015 15:20:32 |  (null) |  (null) |     1.1 |
```

The query picks up only the latest record x=7 due to `ORDER BY "id" DESC` in this code fragment:

```
(  SELECT "value" FROM Table1 t2
      WHERE t2."timestamp" = max( t1."timestamp" )
        AND t2."stream_id" = t1."stream_id"
      ORDER BY "id" DESC LIMIT 1
    ) As val
```

If you want to pick up the first record x=6 instead of the latest, then remove `DESC` from the order by clause.
If you want to sum all records with the same date and stream_id (in the above example - records 6 + 7), then change the above query to:

```
(  SELECT SUM("value") FROM Table1 t2
      WHERE t2."timestamp" = max( t1."timestamp" )
        AND t2."stream_id" = t1."stream_id"
    ) As val
```

And if you want to pick up a random record, then use `ORDER BY random()`.

Comment: Since the sample data provided by me, does not fullfill the requirement "ids and timestamp" are ordered in time, the result in the fiddle is incorrect.

Comment: Here i changed the input data to the requirements but it seems to be incorrect. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/00ae2/1/0

Comment: I've corrected the query, please take a look at it.

Comment: Wow! I just sat there and did not get it ... I am impressed! Thank you!